# Split text of cells into various cells separated by comma using R

Tags: r

I have a data frame as

```
Office 365,MS SQL Server,ASP.NET

Microsoft Azure,ITIL,Project Management

Infrastructure services,AWS solution architect
```

Need to separate this cells by comma as below

```
Office 365                 MS SQL Server                ASP.NET

Microsoft Azure            ITIL                      Project Management

Infrastructure services    AWS solution architect     NA
```

Comment: Reproducible example please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>% separate(text,c("a","b","c"),sep =",",remove =FALSE) %>% select(-1)

                        a                      b                  c
1              Office 365          MS SQL Server            ASP.NET
2         Microsoft Azure                   ITIL Project Management
3 Infrastructure services AWS solution architect               <NA>
```

Due we have not your data, let's assume you have a `data.frame` and you want a `data.frame` as result:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("Office 365,MS SQL Server,ASP.NET",
                              "Microsoft Azure,ITIL,Project Management",
                             "Infrastructure services,AWS solution architect"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a less-than-elegant solution which will get the job done. I'm sure others on SO will bring you more concise methods.

- Essentially, you can use some regex inside of gsub() to extract values before the first comma.
- Once you've done that, delete everything that comes before the first comma, and repeat the process to extract the value before the second comma.
- Repeat as many times as needed.

  ```
  #Load packages
  library(dplyr)
  library(stringr)

  #Replicating your dataset
  df<-data.frame(Strings=
             c("Office 365,MS SQL Server,ASP.NET",
               "Microsoft Azure,ITIL,Project Management",
               "Infrastructure services,AWS solution architect"))

  #Extract sting before the first comma
      df<-mutate(df, FirstComma = gsub(",.*$", "", Strings))

  #Extract string between first & second commas

      #Create a vector identifying end position of First String
      df$EndPosOf1stStr<-str_locate(df$Strings,df$FirstComma)[,2] 

      #Extract string between first & second comma
      df<-mutate(df, STRWithoutFirst = substring(Strings,EndPosOf1stStr+2), 
                 SecondComma = gsub(",.*$", "", STRWithoutFirst))

  #Extract value after second comma

      #Create a vector identifying end position of Second String
      df$EndPosOf2ndStr<-str_locate(df$Strings,df$SecondComma)[,2]

      #Extract string after second comma
      df<-mutate(df,STRWithoutFirstSecond = substring(Strings,EndPosOf2ndStr+2),
        ThirdComma = gsub(",.*$", "", STRWithoutFirstSecond))

  #Keep variables of interest
  df<-select(df, Strings, FirstComma, SecondComma, ThirdComma)

  print(df)
  ```

Comment: Really appreciate that you took the time to comment your code!

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("splitstackshape")
library(splitstackshape)

New_Data = concat.split( Old_Data  , split.col=1, sep = "," , structure = "compact", mode = NULL, type = NULL, drop = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, fill = NA)
```

This worked perfect for me.